# ASP.NET MVC - Post form to html bookmark?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When using a form like this:

```
<h2>
<%:Model.EulaTitle %>
</h2>
<p>
<%=Model.EulaHtml %>
</p>
<a name="errors"></a>
<%:Html.ValidationSummary()%>


<div style="text-align:center;">
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   { %>

<%:Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SourceUrl)%>
<%:Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EulaId)%>


<a name="accept"></a>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<%:Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Accepted)%>
<%:Html.LabelFor(model => model.Accepted)%>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<% } %>
</div>
```

I need the page to scroll to `#errors` when it posts. The `Model.EulaHtml` contains some length EULA text and I'd prefer that the user not have to manually scroll down to see an error message if they post the page without accepting the agreement.

If the controller detects `ModelState.IsValid` on Post, it redirects to another page. If not, I need to stay on this page, but scroll to the `#errors` bookmark anchor tag.

I've thought about just adding '#errors' to the end of the url in the form action, but I receive errors along the line of `a potentially dangerous .... ('%')`. It's possible that I'm incorrectly encoding the hash mark. Anyone else had to deal with this? We're dealing with pretty restrictive requirements for browser compatibility (IE6+ and everything else under the sun) so I try to avoid using JavaScript whenever possible.

**Update**

The error I'm receiving is:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (%).
```

I modifed the `Html.BeginForm()` call to

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm(new { @action="#errors" }))
   { %>
```

And the resulting URL is:

```
http://..../TheControllerName/Eula/%2523errors/
```

I also noticed that a few queryString parameters that were being passed through disappear when I set the `action` attribute in this way.  (Not surprising, but no fix for that is immediately obvious to me)

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? The right way to do it is adding the #errors to the end of the url. After you redirect to the URL with the #errors at the end, do you see the correct address in the address bar of the browser?

Comment: Updated question with error and the generated url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<form action="<%: Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName") %>#errors" method="post">

    <%:Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SourceUrl)%>
    <%:Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EulaId)%>


    <a name="accept"></a>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
    <%:Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Accepted)%>
    <%:Html.LabelFor(model => model.Accepted)%>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

---

You could also write a custom HTML helper that will do the job:

```
public static class FormExtensions
{
    public static MvcForm MyBeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, string fragment)
    {
        var formAction = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(null, actionName, controllerName, htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme, null, fragment, null, htmlHelper.RouteCollection, htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, true);
        var builder = new TagBuilder("form");
        builder.MergeAttribute("action", formAction);
        builder.MergeAttribute("method", "post", true);
        htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
        return new MvcForm(htmlHelper.ViewContext);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
<% using (Html.MyBeginForm("index", "home", "errors")) { %>
    ...
<% }
```

Comment: This is fun: Now, the only thing I see in the content div in the page after posting to `#errors` is the validation summary and the form contents. The HTML for the rest of the page content is still there, but it doesn't display. Grr. Argh.

Comment: Well, you solved the bookmark issue, but I've discovered that any time I link to a bookmark, most of the content disappears from the page. I'll accept this and open another question for that.

Answer (score 6):

Updated MVC 4 solution to the problem:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, null, FormMethod.Post,
     new
        {
            @action = Url.Action("MyAction") + "#bookmark",
            @class = "form-class",
            target = "_blank"
        }))
 {
     ... 
     <input type="submit" value="submit" />

 }
```

Html.BeginForm will generate the validation attributes in your form, using the html `<form>` tag will not.

This call is using the `Html.BeginForm(actionName, controllerName, routeValues, FormMethod, htmlAttributes)` overload, nulling all the routing and assigning the action as an html attribute instead.  The routing is accomplished by using Url.Action(), to which I append my bookmark.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution a bit different to this, using an action filter:

http://spikehd.blogspot.com/2012/01/mvc3-redirect-action-to-html-bookmark.html

It modifies the HTML buffer and outputs a small piece of javascript to instruct the browser to append the bookmark.

Hope it helps :)