# How to post form and append a bookmark

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Using the Razor syntax how would I modify this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SignUp", "Home"))
    { ... }
```

To redirect to a url like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/Home/SignUp/#mybookmark
```

A similar question has been asked but it uses the aspx view engine.

[ASP.NET MVC - Post form to html bookmark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397203/asp-net-mvc-post-form-to-html-bookmark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the extension method I provided in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4397268/29407) all you have to do is replace `<% %>` with `@` in order to Razorify it:

```
@using (Html.MyBeginForm("SignUp", "Home", "mybookmark")) 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just used the Url.ActionLink way as it's easier.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to work out a solution to this, so I thought I would post it on here too:

http://spikehd.blogspot.com/2012/01/mvc3-redirect-action-to-html-bookmark.html

It modifies the HTML buffer and outputs a small piece of javascript to instruct the browser to append the bookmark.

Hope it helps :)