# Ajax call not reaching success or done or whatever MVC3

Tags: jquery, submit

I can't manage to get a simple Ajax to work and return JSON without the browser asking me to save the file... As it stands now however, I can't even get the ajax call to work...  Let me give you a 1000 foot view of what I am trying to accomplish.  I am trying to have 3 tabs... 2 of them, represents two similar yet different ways to search data via a webservice call.  The third tab will display the results in a table when the JSON result returns.  Seems simple enough, and since I have successfully done each of those three components separately I thought the combination would be simple.  Not so.

What is vexing me now, is actually getting the JSON data back to the view and then switching to that tab...  What I am currently experiencing is that I get to the submit function and nothing happens.  It is very frustrating.  First things first, here is the way I set up my form...

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("SearchByDemographic",
          "SearchPatients",
          FormMethod.Post, 
          new{
              id = "searchByDemographics"
          }
      )
 )
```

The form is nothing special.  I want to have jq-validation there at some point, but I will cross that bridge when I get there...  Here is the jquery function that is supposed to call the controller in addition to the function that binds the data to the jqGrid... I have done similar things but not all together...

```
$('#formSearchByMRN, #searchByDemographics').submit(function (event) {
    debugger;
    //event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            debugger;
            //$('#retTable').html(result);
            switchToResultTab(result);
        }
    });
    return false;
});

function switchToResultTab(data) {
    debugger;
    $("#list").setGridParam({
        datatype: 'jsonstring',
        datastr: data,
        caption: 'Patient Search Result'
    }).trigger("reloadGrid");
    $('a[href="#retTable"]').click();
};
```

Currently, when I step through the code, I never get past the debugger function call... That is where it stops!!!!
I am like what on Earth is going on?  How on Earth did I screw up such a simple function call?!  I never get to the  .ajax call???
Lets assume I am being an idiot somewhere, and that I can get the freaking ajax call to work.  Once I do get it there, whenever I get to the success function, my result is always empty.  If I switch to done, the browser asks me to open or save a JSON file...  Does anybody have any general advice,  I know this is kindof specialised, so specific answers may be hard to come by, but could anyone suggest any principles that I may be overlooking here?  How would you go about achieving a similar result?

Thanks

**UPDATE: IT WOULD SEEM AS THOUGH I AM NOT GETTING MY URL OR MY METHOD TYPE**

don't know why calling this.action is not getting the action of the form defined...
I don't know if anybody has any insight on that?  Maybe becuase I am calling two different forms in that function?

**UPDATE**
Ok, I can't seem to get the action or the request type no matter what I do...
If I do this

```
var type = this.action;
```

or

```
var type = $('#searchByDemographics').attr('action');
var type = this.method;
```

or

```
var method = $('#searchByDemographics').attr('method');
```

What on earth am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
I managed to get the action into the action url parameter.  It would seem as though there is nothing that I can do to get this thing to call my method and come back.

```
var urlVal = event.target.action;
```

the above is how I get the action
**The actual HTML: taken from IE**

```
<FORM id=searchByDemographics class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" method=post action=/SearchPatients/SearchByDemographic jQuery1720011976762447693911="75" _submit_attached="true"><UL>
<LI><LABEL for=SSN>SSN</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=SSN name=SSN></LI></UL>
<UL>
<P>Or</P></UL>
<UL>
<LI><LABEL for=FirstName>FirstName</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=FirstName name=FirstName value=Betty></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=LastName>LastName</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=LastName name=LastName value=White></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=dateOfBirth>dateOfBirth</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=dateOfBirth name=dateOfBirth></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=Address1>Address1</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=Address1 name=Address1></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=Address2>Address2</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=Address2 name=Address2></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=City>City</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=City name=City></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=State>State</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=State name=State></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=Country>Country</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=Country name=Country></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=PostCode>PostCode</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=PostCode name=PostCode></LI></UL><INPUT id=submit class=button value="Search By Demographics" type=submit> </FORM>
```

Which would normally be fine.  However, the fact that I have at least two forms on the page is probably complicating something...

```
<DIV id=searchPatient class="float-left ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" jQuery1720011976762447693911="52"><UL class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
<LI class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" jQuery1720011976762447693911="56"><A href="#searchByMRN" jQuery1720011976762447693911="58">Search By MRN</A></LI>
<LI class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active" jQuery1720011976762447693911="57"><A href="#searchByDemographics" jQuery1720011976762447693911="59">Search By Demo</A></LI></UL>
<DIV style="MARGIN-TOP: 6px; DISPLAY: inline; FLOAT: left; MARGIN-LEFT: 6px; MARGIN-RIGHT: 6px" id=searchByMRN class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide">
<FORM id=formSearchByMRN method=post action=/SearchPatients/SearchByMRN?Length=13 data-ajax-update="#retTable" data-ajax-success="switchToResultTab" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax="true">
<P>
<UL>
<LI><LABEL for=MRN>MRN#</LABEL><BR><INPUT id=MRN name=MRN></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=MRNDrop>MRNDrop</LABEL><BR><SELECT id=MRNDrop name=MRNDrop><OPTION selected value=MPACMRN>Medipac</OPTION> <OPTION value=NWMRN>NorthWest</OPTION> <OPTION value=BEDFORD>Epic</OPTION> <OPTION value=CHILDRENS>Bedford</OPTION> <OPTION value=CHILDRENS>Childrens</OPTION> <OPTION value=MAGEE>Magee</OPTION> <OPTION value=PASSAVANT>Passavant</OPTION> <OPTION value=MERCY>Mercy</OPTION> <OPTION value=BEST>Medicare</OPTION> <OPTION value=HEALTHPLAN>UPMC Health Plan</OPTION> <OPTION value=EMPIID>EMPI</OPTION></SELECT></LI></UL>
<P></P><INPUT value="Search by MRN" type=submit> </FORM></DIV>
<DIV style="WIDTH: 50%; DISPLAY: inline; FLOAT: left" id=searchByDemographics class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" jQuery1720011976762447693911="70">
<FORM id=searchByDemographics class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" method=post action=/SearchPatients/SearchByDemographic jQuery1720011976762447693911="75" _submit_attached="true">
<UL>
<LI><LABEL for=SSN>SSN</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=SSN name=SSN></LI></UL>
<UL>
<P>Or</P></UL>
<UL>
<LI><LABEL for=FirstName>FirstName</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=FirstName name=FirstName value=Betty></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=LastName>LastName</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=LastName name=LastName value=White></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=dateOfBirth>dateOfBirth</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=dateOfBirth name=dateOfBirth></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=Address1>Address1</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=Address1 name=Address1></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=Address2>Address2</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=Address2 name=Address2></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=City>City</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=City name=City></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=State>State</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=State name=State></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=Country>Country</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=Country name=Country></LI>
<LI><LABEL for=PostCode>PostCode</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=PostCode name=PostCode></LI></UL><INPUT id=submit class=button value="Search By Demographics" type=submit> </FORM></DIV></DIV>
```

The question is, how does one accurately get the correct form and action...

Comment: It lets you step through your jquery or javascript code.

Comment: Can you please post the output of Html.BeginForm. And why did you remove the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839908/jquery-ui-tabs-switch-on-submit-event-asp-net-mvc-3-returning-json-to-final-ta#comment15264965_10839908. It was the correct answer to that specific question and is an absolutely different question to this one. A bit lame...

Comment: sorry... just trying to get some attention here :)... But I'll post the Html... I know for a fact that I am having a hard time getting the right action and then serializing the right form... I essentially serialize nothing.

Comment: Maybe its a good idea to upload your solution concerning your problem. It's a lot easier to solve a problem in debug mode. Because your desire is not that complicated but I'm not getting your internal project structure.

Comment: Alot of it is hooked up to web services... In fact, the first page calls a web service to get your original table.  You won't be able to get to the first page.  Is there somewhere where we can chat about the project setup?

Comment: I'm afraid but not in the next days. What just gets in my mind is the fact if your ajax call is correctly called there is actually no way that the browser is showing a 'Save as'-dialog. So it more looks like your forms are submitted without even running in your event handler. How are you executing your submits? I guess with buttons of type 'submit'. Try to give them type 'button' and change your event handler to click events. We should try to simplify your code as much as possible.

Comment: I will give that a shot, but why am I unable to serialize my form with a simple $.('formNameHere').serialize() call?