# Jump to error after form post mvc3 .net

Tags: .net, html, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, controller

I have a list of data that prints to the screen.  At the bottom of the screen (with scrolling), I have a form with a text field that the user can enter data in.  When they click submit and the form is not valid, the errors show up correctly, but the user is now looking at the very top of the page.  So, they do not see that there are errors at the bottom of the page.  I would like for it to jump down to the form on the bottom of the page so that the user can see that errors have occurred.

I thought about using anchors, but the problem with that is; since I'm already in the controller when I realize the form is not valid, I would need to redirect back to the same controller attaching the hashtag to the url.  To me, this does not see like good practice and a bit of a waste.

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you averse to client-side validation? That would show the error the second they clicked Submit without posting..

Comment: jQuery Solution - 
Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363508/scroll-to-validation-summary-asp-net-mvc/9382969#9382969

Comment: Well, there's two issues, one, I linked MicrosoftAjax.js, MicrosoftMvcAjax.js, and MicrosoftMvcValidation.js.  I also have: 

<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

But, I when I run in debug mode, it is still hitting my Controller.  Also, I would like this solution if they have JS turned off.

Comment: One straightforward solution would be to add a global error message at the top of the page when there were errors in the form. This is usually what I do (when I have validation rules that are present only on the server side)

Comment: rid yourself of the microsoftmvc and ajax files, stick to jquery files only and all will still work ok. Without a hash tag and JS you have no other cross browser option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to always post to an anchor and in the view determine where to put the anchor.  If there are model errors then place the named anchor at the bottom of the page, if there is no error then place the anchor at the top of the page.  One thing complicating this is that there is no Html.BeginForm overload that takes an anchor.  You could achieve it simply like this

```
<form action="@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")#anchor_name" method="post">

    ..... form contents .....

</form>
```

or you could write a custom HTML helper

```
public static class FormExtensions
{
    public static MvcForm CustomBeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, string fragment)
    {
        var formAction = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(null, actionName, controllerName, htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme, null, fragment, null, htmlHelper.RouteCollection, htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, true);
        var builder = new TagBuilder("form");
        builder.MergeAttribute("action", formAction);
        builder.MergeAttribute("method", "post", true);
        htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
        return new MvcForm(htmlHelper.ViewContext);
    }
}
```

Then you could use `@Html.CustomBeginForm('action', 'controller', 'anchor_name')`

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397203/asp-net-mvc-post-form-to-html-bookmark) is useful and informed my answer

Comment: Thanks, I ended up creating my own custom form because I wanted to be able to set the id of the form also.  I will post my code below.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static MvcForm BeginFormAnchor(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, FormMethod method, object htmlAttributes, string hashTag)
    {
        var formAction = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(null, actionName, controllerName, htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme, null, hashTag, ConvertToRouteValueDictionary(routeValues), htmlHelper.RouteCollection, htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, true);
        var builder = new TagBuilder("form");
        builder.MergeAttribute("action", formAction);
        builder.MergeAttribute("method", method.ToString(), true);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> attribute in ConvertToDictionaryStringString(htmlAttributes))
        {
            builder.MergeAttribute(attribute.Key, attribute.Value);
        }
        htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
        return new MvcForm(htmlHelper.ViewContext);
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, string> ConvertToDictionaryStringString(object obj)
    {
        return obj.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(o => o.Name, o => o.GetValue(obj, null).ToString());
    }

    private static RouteValueDictionary ConvertToRouteValueDictionary(object obj)
    {
        RouteValueDictionary rvd = new RouteValueDictionary();
        PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj);
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
        {
            rvd.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(obj));
        }
        return rvd;
    }
```

I call it in the form like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginFormAnchor("Action", "Controller", new { id = Model.ID }, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "formID" }, "anchorName"))
```